# How to count XML node occurence into a for-each or xsl:template using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I would like to count every occurrence of an XML node containing a dynamic specific value which I know only by reading the node.

I tried to count the xml node with XPath in my first try with a for-each but it seems to be blocked in the current row and can't count the occurrences.

Now with xsl:template, I thought that I could extract the correct value but I can't.

XML Input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLCreators>
    <row>
        <element0>0313409760492014833</element0>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element0>0310709773371838642</element0>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element0>0313809763241653098</element0>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element0>0115709728654070781</element0>
    </row>
    <row>
        <element0>0110009760492014833</element0>
    </row>
</XMLCreators>
```

Output I need :

```
<liste xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
   <nm id="760492014833">
      <count>2</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="773371838642">
      <count>1</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="763241653098">
      <count>1</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="728654070781">
      <count>1</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="760492014833">
      <count>2</count>
   </nm>
</liste>
```

Output I have with my XSLT

```
<liste xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
   <nm id="760492014833">
      <count>0</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="773371838642">
      <count>0</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="763241653098">
      <count>0</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="728654070781">
      <count>0</count>
   </nm>
   <nm id="760492014833">
      <count>0</count>
   </nm>
</liste>
```

My XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" /> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <liste>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </liste>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XMLCreators">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element0"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element0">
        <xsl:variable name="idNM" select="normalize-space(substring(., 8, 14))" />
        <nm>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$idNM"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <count>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[contains(element0,'$idNM')])" />
            </count>
        </nm>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the apostrophes around the use of the variable in contains, otherwise it will be literally looking for a string "$idNM" rather than the value of the variable

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[contains(element0,$idNM)])" />
```

Do you really mean to use `contains` here though, as this will count elements where the string is at the start too? If you only wanted to count strings where it occurs at the end, do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(//*[substring(element0, 8, 14) = $idNM])" />
```

Comment: Perfect !! So tired, I forgot the apostrophe ! you save me ! Thank you.   In my case, I have more data in my element0, that's why it seems to be the end of the node value in this example.